# Specifying an attribute for multiple Objective-C Methods declarations

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, clang, llvm

By consulting the [document](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#specifying-an-attribute-for-multiple-declarations-pragma-clang-attribute), I know that you can add annotate to C functions in the following ways

```
#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((annotate("custom"))), apply_to = function)

void function(); // The function now has the annotate("custom") attribute
void function1(); 
void function2(); 
#pragma clang attribute pop
```

But it will report an error in Objective-C method

Error message:

[image]

```
@implementation STAppDelegate

#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((annotate("custom"))), apply_to = objc_method)

- (void)a {
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
}

- (void)b {
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
}

- (void)c {
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
}

#pragma clang attribute pop

@end
```

Comment: The image tells me the trouble is that you need to write strings in Objective-C as ```@"string"``` and not ```"string"```. Nothing to do with the annotation but everything with the ```@``` modifier.

Comment: or go with `fprintf(stderr,"string");` instead of `NSLog()`

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the wrong picture, and now I have uploaded the correct picture, I still get an error

Comment: You : ... uploaded wrong picture ... Me : Just punishment for using pictures in stead of code. Anyhow, it should work. Check your compiler flags - must be clang. Also, push and pop needs to be balanced. Working fine this side, using your exact push and pop lines pasted into my code.

Comment: I know the cause of the problem, I used a relatively low version of Xcode, its clang version is relatively low, does not support

Answer (score 0):

It will work on Objective-C class **interface** level e.g.

```
#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((annotate("custom"))), apply_to = objc_method)
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
-(void)yourMethod;
@end
#pragma clang attribute pop

#pragma clang attribute push(__attribute__((annotate("custom2"))), apply_to = objc_method)

@interface AppDelegate ()
-(void)yourMethod2;
@end

@interface AppDelegate ()
-(void)yourMethod3;
@end
#pragma clang attribute pop
```